# Writing a command which takes multiple inputs in a single line

Tags: bash, cmd, command-line, command, pipe

I should run this command:.

`mosquitto_ctrl -u admin -P admin dynsec createClient User`

After running the command, it asks me for an input twice like this:

> Enter new password for User. Press return for no password (user will be unable to login).

> New password for User:

and then:

> Reenter password for User:

How could I do everything in a single line?
I tried with something like this:

`echo {"password":"password"} | mosquitto_ctrl -u admin -P admin dynsec createClient User`

But it didn't work. How could I do?

I need to give 2 different inputs to one single command, so I can create users automatically.

Comment: Try `printf "$password\n$password\n" | mosquitto...`

Comment: Is there an equivalent in Windows?

Comment: No idea what crazy way Microsoft might force upon you, maybe `( ECHO %password% ; ECHO %password% ) | mosquitto.exe ...`

Comment: It only takes the first input, as every other attempt I made... thank you anyway

Comment: @MarkSetchell nearly: `(ECHO %password%&ECHO %password%) | mosquitto.exe ...` or `(ECHO s3cret&ECHO s3cret) | mosquitto.exe ...` Attention: no spaces, or they become part of the password!

Comment: I don't kno w why but it seems it doesn't take the second password as input and it only creates user without password, because it only takes the first password and not the second one

Comment: If `mosquitto_ctrl` clears the buffer before asking, there is nothing you can do about it with this method. You'd need to provide the strings in realtime instead (which batch/cmd isn't able to do; look for `sendkey` and `vbs`).